# column-toggle not working in jquery mobile 1.3.2, backboneJS and RequireJS with $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, cordova, requirejs

I am having some trouble when I open a dialog in [Table: Column Toggle](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/table-column-toggle/). I use BackboneJS, RequireJS, JQuery Mobile, Phonegap 3.0

My configuration for prevent jquery routing is:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {

                    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
                    $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
                    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
                    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
                    $(document).delegate('div[data-role="page"]', 'pagehide', function (event, ui) {
                                          $(event.currentTarget).remove();
                                          });
                     });
```

and in my HTML I have JQuery Mobile sample:

```
<table data-role="table" id="table-custom-2" data-mode="columntoggle" class="ui-body-d ui-shadow table-stripe ui-responsive" data-column-btn-theme="b" data-column-btn-text="Columns to display..." data-column-popup-theme="a">
     <thead>
       <tr class="ui-bar-d">
         <th data-priority="2">Rank</th>
         <th>Movie Title</th>
         <th data-priority="3">Year</th>
         <th data-priority="1"><abbr title="Rotten Tomato Rating">Rating</abbr></th>
         <th data-priority="5">Reviews</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
         <th>1</th>
         <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citizen_Kane" data-rel="external">Citizen Kane</a></td>
         <td>1941</td>
         <td>100%</td>
         <td>74</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>2</th>
         <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_(film)" data-rel="external">Casablanca</a></td>
         <td>1942</td>
         <td>97%</td>
         <td>64</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>3</th>
         <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godfather" data-rel="external">The Godfather</a></td>
         <td>1972</td>
         <td>97%</td>
         <td>87</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>4</th>
         <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gone_with_the_Wind_(film)" data-rel="external">Gone with the Wind</a></td>
         <td>1939</td>
         <td>96%</td>
         <td>87</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>5</th>
         <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lawrence_of_Arabia_(film)" data-rel="external">Lawrence of Arabia</a></td>
         <td>1962</td>
         <td>94%</td>
         <td>87</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>6</th>
         <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Strangelove" data-rel="external">Dr. Strangelove Or How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb</a></td>
         <td>1964</td>
         <td>92%</td>
         <td>74</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>7</th>
         <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Graduate" data-rel="external">The Graduate</a></td>
         <td>1967</td>
         <td>91%</td>
         <td>122</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>8</th>
         <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wizard_of_Oz_(1939_film)" data-rel="external">The Wizard of Oz</a></td>
         <td>1939</td>
         <td>90%</td>
         <td>72</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>9</th>
         <td><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singin%27_in_the_Rain" data-rel="external">Singin' in the Rain</a></td>
         <td>1952</td>
         <td>89%</td>
         <td>85</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <th>10</th>
         <td class="title"><a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception" data-rel="external">Inception</a></td>
         <td>2010</td>
         <td>84%</td>
         <td>78</td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
   </table>
```

Can i open a dialog via javascript?

Comment: Have you placed `mobileinit` binding code after jquery library and before JQM?

Comment: @Omar yes, mobileinit is into require(['order!jQuery'], function($) {...} and after I load JQuery Mobile

Comment: @FlavioBontà did you managed to solve this problem ? Im having exactly the same issue

Comment: @zzart i've used a simple table. I've found other problems, solved via javascript, example dialog for me working only `$("#selector").dialog();`. But for column-toggle there isn't an API for this problem.

Comment: A related issue? [Github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6673)